# Loop through variable in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Please forgive me... new to python and first question on stack.

I'm trying to accomplish two things with while loop:

1. increment round number (i'm doing this successfully)
2. have the loop iterate over my variable "fruits" to print the first fruit on round one and second fruit on round two

variables:

round_number = 0
fruit = [apple, orange, banana]

python code:

```
while round_number < 5:
    round_number += 1
    print("Round Number: ", round_number) 

 for item in fruit:
      print(item)
```

the above code is what I currently have. When I run the code it prints all items in my fruit variable at once.

My desired output is for the print output to look like this:

Round Number: 1
apples

Round Number: 2
oranges

ect...

Comment: And what would happen after 3??

Comment: Im assuming the whole output it some like: 1 apple, orange, banana, 2 apple orange banana. then when it gets to 4 it will error out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use the *while-loop* then you can write your code as this:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
round_number = 0

while round_number < len(fruit):
    round_number += 1
    print("Round Number: ", round_number, fruit[round_number-1])
```

and for the *for-loop* then your code will be:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
round_number = 0

for item in fruit:
    print("Round Number: ", fruit.index(item)+1, item)
```

hope this help

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with `enumerate`:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
for n, f in enumerate(fruit, start=1):
    print(f'Round Number: {n} {f}s')
```

Output:

```
Round Number: 1 apples
Round Number: 2 oranges
Round Number: 3 bananas
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the index instead of a counter.

Try getting the index of the item in the list, and adding 1. Then joining the string together for the print

```
for x in fruit:
    print('Round Number: ' + str(fruit.index(x)+1), x)
```

Comment: This has two problems: it's slow, and it won't work as expected if the list contains duplicate items.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using asynchronous stuff, things will happen in the order they're written. The first loop executes entirely, and then the second loop executed entirely.

This is why youll get an output looking like this

```
Round Number:  1
Round Number:  2
Round Number:  3
Round Number:  4
Round Number:  5
apple
orange
banana
```

If you want to output the index of a variable in your list, followed by the variable, you'd want to do that in a single loop.

The way to do this you'd learn starting out looks like this

```py
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

for i in range(len(fruit)): 
  print(i+1, fruit[i])
```

However, the pythonic way to do this would use the enumerate method

```py
for i, fruitName in enumerate(fruit):
  print(i+1, fruitName)
```

It would also be good to get used to string formatting

```py
for i, fruitName in enumerate(fruit):
  print(f'{i+1}: {fruitName}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize the enumerate function to start the number from 1

```
for i, item in enumerate(fruits, start=1):
   print(i, item)
```

Alternatively, you can use for loop

```
for i, item in range(len(fruit)):
   print(i+1, fruit[i])
```